# jQuery clock 12/24 hour together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I meant to have two clocks, one for 24-hour format, and the other is 12-hour format,

```
function updateClock() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var currentHoursAP = currentTime.getHours();
    var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
    var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

    // Pad the minutes and seconds with leading zeros, if required
    currentMinutes = (currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentMinutes;
    currentSeconds = (currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentSeconds;

    // Choose either "AM" or "PM" as appropriate
    var timeOfDay = (currentHours < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";

    // Convert the hours component to 12-hour format if needed
    currentHoursAP = (currentHours > 12) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;

    // Convert an hours component of "0" to "12"
    currentHoursAP = (currentHours == 0) ? 12 : currentHours;

    // Compose the string for display
    var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + " / " + currentHoursAP + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;

    $("#clock").html(currentTimeString);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
});
```

but end up to `currentHours` and `currentHoursAP` become exact same value.
What do I missed?

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger and find out for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was

```
// Convert an hours component of "0" to "12"
currentHoursAP = (currentHoursAP == 0) ? 12 : currentHoursAP;
```

if `currentHoursAP != 0`  then instead of setting back the value of `currentHoursAP` you were setting it back to `currentHours`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CqN2S/)

Answer (score 1):

`getHours` is zero-based (`0 = 12 AM, 23 = 11 PM`), so you need to adjust the check:

```
currentHoursAP = (currentHours >= 12) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;
currentHoursAP = (currentHoursAP == 0) ? 12 : currentHoursAP;
```